# Use a Groovy script (with a call method defined) in another script file

Tags: groovy

I have a shared Jenkins library code `getConfig.groovy` that defines some configuration values. I'd like to use this same config file in another script `pipeline.groovy` (on another system outside of Jenkins). Both files are in the same directory.

File `pipeline.groovy`

```
def config = getConfig()
def regionConfig = config.find { it.region == 'value1' }

println regionConfig['prop2']
```

File `getConfig.groovy`

```
def call() {
    return [
            [
                    region: 'value1',
                    prop2: 'value2',
                    prop3: 'value3',
            ]
    ]
}
```

I'm getting this error when running `pipeline.groovy`

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: pipeline.getConfig() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getBinding(), getClass()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: pipeline.getConfig() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Without modifying `getConfig.groovy`, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
def loadInstance(String file){
  File sourceFile = new File(file)
  Class groovyClass = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile)
  return (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance()
}

def getConfig = loadInstance("getConfig.groovy")
def config = getConfig()
...
```